# Implementation of slider on bottomsheet in flutter

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

How to implement slider inside the bottomsheet in flutter. I tried it but slider didn't move along. But it worked if  I put  slider in a new scaffold. Help me. Thanks in advance.

here this is my code.

```
                          new InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  //  fire_ac_on_1();
                                },
                               onDoubleTap:(){
                                  _showModalSheet_ac();

                                }

                                onLongPress: () {
                                  selectTime(context);
                                },
                                child: new IconButton(
                                  icon: new Image.asset('images/ac.png',
                                      color: ac_on_state == true ? Colors
                                          .green : Colors.redAccent),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    fire_ac_on();
                                  },
                                  iconSize: 80.0,
                                ),
                              ),
```

// ModalBottom Sheet
void _showModalSheet_ac(){

```
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
//print(height);
showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (builder){
  return new Container(
    height: height - 200.0,
      child: new Center(
        child:  new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
             child: new Slider(
              value: slider_value,
           onChanged: onchanged),

          )
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
  );
});
```

}

onchanged(double value) {

```
 setState(() {
  slider_value = value;

});
print(slider_value);
```

}

Comment: please add some of code which you tried.

Comment: I added. thanks for ur response.

Answer (score 16):

bottomSheet is not stateful which is why it does not rebuild when you call setState in your Slider.

You'll have to wrap your Slider widget with StatefulBuilder.

```
        StatefulBuilder(
          builder: (context, setState){
            return Slider(
              value: _value,
              onChanged: (selection){
                setState(() {
                  _value = selection;
                });
              },
            );
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved the same issue using `StreamBuilder` and RxDart:

```dart
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

final _slider = PublishSubject<double>();
Observable<double> get sliderStream => _slider.stream;

void _settingModalBottomSheet(context){
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext bc){
          return StreamBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<double> snapshot) {
              return Slider(
                  activeColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
                  min: 0.0,
                  max: 15.0,
                  onChanged: (newRating) {
                    _slider.sink.add(newRating);
                  },
                  value: snapshot.data,
                );
            },
            initialData: 0.0,
            stream: sliderStream,
          );
        }
    );
  }
```

On every `onChanged` event you'll ***emit*** the new slider's value (`_slider.sink.add(newRating);`). The `StreamBuilder` will be notified every time the slider's value change, and will rebuild the widget with the updated value (`value: snapshot.data`).

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass **BuildContext** to the **builder** instead of builder. i hope that Following example may help you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Bottom modal tutorial',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Bottom modal tutorial'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  mainBottomSheet(BuildContext context){
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context){
          return Container(
            height: 300.0,
              child: Center(child: new Text("Demo Text"))
          );
        }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: new Center(
          child: new Text(
            'Body',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => mainBottomSheet(context),
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply. The problem is not about the bottomsheet it works fine but the real problm is slider doesn't  slide in the bottomsheet dynamically. thanks indeed for your response.

Comment: I tried putting Buildcontext in place of builder like you said but nothing happens. any other suggestions please??